# C# how do i convert a char that i get from serial comunication to an array with every bit in a different slot

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

i get an 8 bit data from a microcontroller that i want split up in bits to be able to look at evry single bit individualy

i tried doing this

```
`data = char.Parse( serial.ReadExisting());
this.lstOntvang.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate ()
{
lstOntvang.Items.Add(data);

BitArray dataBits = new BitArray(new byte[] {byte.Parse(data.ToString())});
byte[] bits = new byte[8];
dataBits.CopyTo(bits, 0);
Array.Reverse(bits);
if (bits[0] == 1)    lblV10.ForeColor = Color.Red;
else                        lblV10.ForeColor = Color.Black;
if (bits[1] == 1)    lblV50.ForeColor = Color.Orange;
else                        lblV50.ForeColor = Color.Black;
if (bits[2] == 1)    lblV90.ForeColor = Color.Green;
else                        lblV90.ForeColor = Color.Black;
if (bits[3] == 1)    lblVbak.ForeColor = Color.Green;
else                        lblVbak.ForeColor = Color.Red;
if (bits[4] == 1)    lblW10.ForeColor = Color.Red;
else                        lblW10.ForeColor = Color.Black;
if (bits[5] == 1)    lblW50.ForeColor = Color.Orange;
else                        lblW50.ForeColor = Color.Black;
if (bits[6] == 1)    lblW90.ForeColor = Color.Green;
else                        lblW90.ForeColor = Color.Black;
if (bits[7] == 1)    lblWbak.ForeColor=Color.Green;
else                        lblWbak.ForeColor = Color.Red;
}));`
```

Comment: You can check if a specific bit is set by applying bitwise AND between the byte and an appropriate power of 2. This way of "filtering" bits is often called masking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is that you can map the bits of a byte instantaneously to an enum that you set up for this purpose. Now you have a usable value representing the labels whose bits are set and can use the `HasFlag(Enum flag)` method to test whether a particular bit is `true`..

`LabelName setLabels = (LabelName)serial.ReadExisting()`.

[image: example]

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Usage: LabelName setLabels = (LabelName) byteValue.
/// </summary>
[Flags]
enum LabelName : byte // Casting 'any' byte to this enum instantly maps the bits. 
{
    [SetColor("Red")]
    lblV10 = 0x01,

    [SetColor("Orange")]
    lblV50 = 0x02,

    [SetColor("Green")]
    lblV90 = 0x04,

    [SetColor("Green")]
    lblVBak = 0x08,

    [SetColor("Red")]
    lblW10 = 0x10,

    [SetColor("Orange")]
    lblW50 = 0x20,

    [SetColor("Green")]
    lblW90 = 0x40,

    [SetColor("Green")]
    lblWbak = 0x80,
}
```

---

###### [SetColor] attribute

In this case, we've made a simple custom attribute named `SetColor` to easily specify the background color that should be applied to the label when the flag is set. (This is optional.)

```
sealed class SetColorAttribute : Attribute
{
    public SetColorAttribute(string color) => Value = Color.FromName(color);
    public Color Value { get; }
}
```

---

###### Example

If the enumeration name is *also* an exact match for the `Label.Name` property on the form, you can use it to retrieve the label control using the string indexer of the `Controls` collection that contains the labels. (For example `tableLayoutPanel.Controls[name]`). Here's a simple form that brings all the elements together.

```cs
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        buttonReadExisting.Click += (sender, e) =>
        {
            // Generate sim data byte
            byte data = MockReadExisting();
            labelByte.Text = $"0x{data:X2}";

            foreach (LabelName name in Enum.GetValues(typeof(LabelName)))
            {
                if (tableLayoutPanel.Controls[$"{name}"] is Label label)
                {
                    if (((LabelName)data).HasFlag(name))
                    {
                        if(
                            typeof(LabelName)
                            .GetMember($"{name}")
                            .FirstOrDefault()?
                            .GetCustomAttribute(typeof(SetColorAttribute))
                            is
                            SetColorAttribute attr)
                        {
                            label.BackColor = attr.Value;
                        }
                        else label.BackColor = Color.Maroon; // Fallback
                    }
                    else label.BackColor = Color.Black;
                }
            }
        };
    }
```

###### Simulate the received byte (sequentially or randomly)

```
    bool UseRandom { get; set; } = true;
    int count = 1;
    private byte MockReadExisting()
    {
        if(UseRandom) return Convert.ToByte(_rando.Next(0x100));
        else return Convert.ToByte(((count++) % 0xFF));
    }
    Random _rando = new Random(2);
}
```

Comment: [Clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/color-flags.git)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do that is masking what you are reciving from your serial.
Try using the AND bitwise operator:

```
byte data = (byte)char.Parse(serial.ReadExisting());
this.lstOntvang.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate() {
    lstOntvang.Items.Add(data);

    if ((data & 1) != 0) lblV10.ForeColor = Color.Red;
    else lblV10.ForeColor = Color.Black;
    if ((data & 2) != 0) lblV50.ForeColor = Color.Orange;
    else lblV50.ForeColor = Color.Black;
    if ((data & 4) != 0) lblV90.ForeColor = Color.Green;
    else lblV90.ForeColor = Color.Black;
    if ((data & 8) != 0) lblVbak.ForeColor = Color.Green;
    else lblVbak.ForeColor = Color.Red;
    if ((data & 16) != 0) lblW10.ForeColor = Color.Red;
    else lblW10.ForeColor = Color.Black;
    if ((data & 32) != 0) lblW50.ForeColor = Color.Orange;
    else lblW50.ForeColor = Color.Black;
    if ((data & 64) != 0) lblW90.ForeColor = Color.Green;
    else lblW90.ForeColor = Color.Black;
    if ((data & 128) != 0) lblWbak.ForeColor = Color.Green;
    else lblWbak.ForeColor = Color.Red;
}));
```